# C3 - line chart time series error: x is not defined for id = "Dates"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I'm trying to add a time series as an x axis to my two-line chart in C3. Unfortunately I can't figure out quite how to do it. It's giving the error "x is not defined for id = "Dates"" although I've tried to follow C3's timeseries chart example as closely as possible.

Here's the code, any ideas?

```
request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            var throughputReceived = JSON.parse(this.responseText).throughputReceived,
                throughputSent = JSON.parse(this.responseText).throughputSent,
                date = JSON.parse(this.responseText).date,
                chart,
                length = throughputReceived.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                throughputReceived[i] /= 1000000;
                throughputSent[i] /= 1000000;
                //                date[i] = moment(date[i]).format("YYYY MM DD hh ss");
            }

            throughputReceived.unshift('Throughput Received (Mbps)');
            throughputSent.unshift('Throughput Sent (Mbps)');
            date.unshift('Dates');

            chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: container,
                data: {
                    x: date,
                    columns: [date, throughputReceived, throughputSent]
                },
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        //                        label: 'Test No.'
                        type: 'timeseries',
                        tick: {
                            format: '%Y %m %d %h %s'
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        label: {
                            text: 'Throughput (Mbps)',
                            position: 'outer-top'
                        },
                        tick: {
                            format: d3.format('.2f')
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Impossible to answer this question without knowing what your data looks like...

Comment: Sorry - the 'date' field is an date/time array that has been parsed by moment.js to be in "YYYY MM DD hh ss" format and the other two are just arrays of numbers. So far I've got the graph working with 'throughputReceived' and 'throughputSent' but now I'd like to use the new variable 'date' as the x axis for the graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining your x-axis wrong.

Instead of referencing your array of dates, you have to define the title of your column.

```
date.unshift('Awesome-Column');
...
data: {
        x: 'Awesome-Column',
        columns: [date, throughputReceived, throughputSent]
       },
```